# MediaController method adjustVolume and MediaSession

Tags: java, android, audio

I am implementing an audio player which uses the MediaController and MediaSession classes.
I have been able to implement the transport controls (play, pause, rewind ...) using sample code and implementing the MediaSession.Callback class to handle the MediaController.TransportControls.  Please also note that I am relatively new to Android development.

I have started to look at how to handle the audio commands and noticed MediaController has adjustVolume() and setVolumeTo() methods defined.

**My question is:  Why aren't volume commands (and possibly other audio commands like BTBF, EQ settings ...) handled in a manner similar to the transport commands?
In other words, why isn't there a MediaController.AudioControls class that could then be handled by the MediaSession callbacks?**

I see there is an MediaController.PlaybackInfo class which provides various information about the audio. 
There is also a sendCommand() method in the MediaController class which is handled by the onCommand()  callback in MediaSession.Callback.  Similarly there is SendCustomAction() method defined in MediaController.TransportControls which is handled by onCustomAction() in MediaSession.Callback.
I am tempted to use these commands to adjust various aspects of the audio playback but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking classes that are meant to achieve this.  It just seems the MediaSession class could have additional methods (additional nested class?)  to handle the audio control in a manner similar to the transport controls. 
Thanks in advance.
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs or controls exposed by MediaController are the most common uses cases concerned with remote control from either the lockscreen, notifications or headset media buttons.

1. The [MediaController#sendCommand(String command, Bundle args, ResultReceiver cb)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver)) was designed for app specific custom commands between your application UI and the service managing the MediaSession. This is well suited for the specific usecase you have in mind w.r.t EQ settings.
2. [MediaController.TransportControls#sendCustomAction(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.TransportControls.html#sendCustomAction(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) on the other hand is for any PlaybackState.CustomAction(s) which can be displayed by other apps. An example of a CustomAction would be say marking an item as a favorite. (You can see how this is implemented in the MusicService class in the [MediaBrowserService](http://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService) sample)

Also note that there is a [VolumeProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/VolumeProvider.html) class that can be set on the session to receive callbacks about changes/set. In the absence of this, the session handles updates to volume.

Comment: I would like to ask a follow up question related to the MediaController.  Our application will be in focus while we are providing audio.  It seems in a lot of cases the MediaController and MediaSession are mentioned in the context of remote control.  My question is:  Is it incorrect to   use  the MediaController and MediaSession pattern if we are not in a remote control use case?  (I am thinking this  does not break any fundamental rules.) Thanks again.

Comment: Answer from core android engineer: MediaSession can be used in an Activity or a Service. It's designed for any time you want to handle media button events or you would like information about what's playing to be available to the system and other devices (such as on Wear). It can also be used for controls between your app's processes if you don't want to write your own-it only gets published when you call setActive(true).
Also take a look at Activity.setMediaController as a way to receive media button events while in the foreground.

Comment: @NageshSusarla: The VolumeProvider doesn't seem to be working for me, could you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070501/onvolumechanged-not-called)?