# onAdjustVolume not called

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediasession

I am trying to get HARDWARE_HOOK button and volume change button in my service using MediaSession for Android 5.0+ . This has to work specially when screen is off/locked.
The problem is that though I am able to receive HARDWARE_HOOK button event, the volume change is not detected. the onAdjustVolume method never gets called.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRouter;
import android.media.session.MediaSession;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HookButtonService extends Service{

    public static final String SESSION_TAG = "SampleApp";

    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;

    private VolumeProviderCompat myVolumeProvider;

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {

        public HookButtonService getService() {
            return HookButtonService.this;
        }
    }

    private Binder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    private MediaSessionCompat.Callback mMediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            Log.d("SampleApp","Media button received");
            if(!MyApplication.isActivityVisible()) {
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };



    public HookButtonService() {
    }

    public MediaSessionCompat.Token getMediaSessionToken() {
        return mMediaSession.getSessionToken();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, SESSION_TAG);
        mMediaSession.setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback);

        myVolumeProvider = new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, 100, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                Log.d("SampleApp","Volume change received: "+direction);

            }
        };

        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackToRemote(myVolumeProvider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaSession.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you get a call to onMediaButtonEvent when you press the volume buttons?

Comment: @pantos27: onMediaButtonEvent gets called on Play/Pause button but not volume buttons.

Comment: any luck few years later...?

Answer (score 0):

`onAdjustVolume` and `VolumeProviderCompat` are desired to work with remote displays, when you play some music/video using casting. method won't fire when you are using on-device buttons during e.g. silence and screen-off. confusing class name, its not so universal as it sounds...

afaik at the beginning of 2021 there is no reliable way for intercepting volume button presses when screen off, probably even detecting... (@op if you found solution please post)

The reason is probably that this is one of intended "features" of Android for reducing battery draining during screen off - distributing button presses straight to lower audio-managing layers ommiting framework/apps, not allowing to execute some additional code (which we want to do)

Comment: it works on Samsung S22 Ultra on Android 14 but doesn't work for Pixel Emulator on Android 14, though it works for devices and emulators on Android 11 and lower. For 12-13 it doesn't work or randomly for some devices like with Android 14 on Samsung

Comment: `method won't fire when you are using on-device buttons during e.g. silence and screen-off` - well, it's not really correct, cause it works for newer some devices and for all older phones (Android 11-) even if the screen is off -  `onAdjustVolume` is definitely called